# BreezeJs and AngularJs startup help - how to revieve data from url

Tags: angularjs, breeze, dataservice

I have created the following application in Angular js. This retrieves data from the github api "https://api.github.com/users/angular" via $http.get method in angular. So I want to do the same thing by using BreezeJs to retrieve data in the most simplest way. Please help me to do this. Provide a sample code if possible.

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app>

 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="data.js"></script>
 </head>

<body ng-controller="database">
  <h2>Database data</h2>
  <h3>{{responce}}</h3>
  <div>User id: {{user.id}}</div>
  <div>User name: {{user.name}}</div>
  <div>Created date: {{user.created_at}}</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

**data.js**

```
var database = function($scope, $http){

  $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/angular")
    .then(success, error);

  var success = function(response){
    $scope.user = response.data;

    $scope.responce = "Data recieved";
    $scope.status = "success";
  }

  var error = function(err){
    $scope.responce = "404 Not found";
    $scope.status = "failed";
    $scope.new = err.data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Here is a Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/sTMzICATSG2cI1LPO1eG?p=info) that demonstrates how to query the github api for Angular team members using Breeze.

Here's the query ... most of it explained in the README.md:

```
 return breeze.EntityQuery
    .from('orgs/angular/members')
    .toType('Member')
    .using(manager)
    .execute().then(success).catch(failed);
```

Breeze can query any HTTP endpoint and return the data to you. But it's more interesting to turn those data into Breeze entities. That takes metadata. In this example we show how to create metadata that defines the Member type ... and arrange for the query results to become Breeze Member entities.

Enjoy!